# Replacing a string with the same string and a random suffix

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

d={'ID':["x1", "x2", "x1"],
'CUSIP':['a', 'b', "#NULL"],
'ISIN':["#NULL", "#NULL", 'I']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

I want to replace the "#NULL" with a suffix that has a random number suffix. Something like:"#NULL_xyz" where _xyz is a randomly generated number for each "#NULL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda val: val + ("_" + str(random.randint(0, 1000)) if val == '#NULL' else ''))
```

and replace the range `(0, 1000)` to whatever random range you want.

To use following numbers you can use a generator:

```
def myGen():
    for i in range(-1, 1000):
        yield(i)
df = df.applymap(lambda val: val + ("_" + str(next(a)) if val == '#NULL' else ''))
```

Comment: thanks ! rather than a random number between 0 and 1000, is there a way to generate numbers sequentially from 0 to 1000 ? ie #NULL_0, #NULL_1 etc ?

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.Series.str.replace` can use `callable` to replace:

```
import random

for c in df:
    df[c] = df[c].str.replace('(#NULL)', lambda x: '{}_{}'.format(x.group(0), random.randint(0, 10)))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      CUSIP  ID     ISIN
0         a  x1  #NULL_8
1         b  x2  #NULL_5
2  #NULL_10  x1        I
```